# Managing Temporary Files Created by an IDE in Git

Tags: git, ide

Currently I am working in Atmel's AVR Studio 7.0 (based off of VS2015-shell) which has some funky behavior when it comes to the temporary files that get created when the IDE runs. Before going any further I want to say that I am not interested in the underlying problem with Atmel Studio, that would be a different question for a different website. Instead I am going to ask with how to deal with the behavior in the short term, in terms of managing the files in my repository.

So anyway, I will explain what happens to give an idea of what I'm dealing with. Each C++ project that gets created in Atmel Studio has a solution (`.atsln` file) that goes along with it. Then, along with each solution is a `.atsuo` file. The `.atsuo` file gets modified every time that the solution gets closed. My problem with this is that I am trying to check everything into a repository and it doesn't really make sense to check that file in because it will change even if I just open the project once, run it, and close it...

Now, let me get to the really good part... As much as I'd like to just *not* check the `.atsuo` file in, I am forced to... If the `.atsuo` file gets deleted then the solution file will not ever work again, I'll get "Atmel AVR Studio 7.0 has stopped working..." then just crashes. So it's like I am being forced to check that file in if I don't want to have to build a new solution every single time! But I don't want to because it keeps changing!!!

What on earth can I do to manage this file in Git?

**Update**

At the end of the day, the changed contents of the `.atsuo` don't do any harm.

Comment: It's simple, you use a different tool which does not generate this mess. /s

Comment: @DavidPacker That's the long term answer. The question is not about the tool though actually, it's more along the lines of... do I just deal with the file sitting in the repository and revert it whenever it changes? Or just expect whoever pulls the project to rebuild the solution?

Comment: Just add it to your gitignore. You can use the one I created. https://github.com/rubberduck203/XMega-A1-XPlored/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: @RubberDuck What do you do when you clone a project though? Will your AVR studio actually handle the solution? Because I thought about that, but then I'd be right back where I started.

Comment: It's a user settings file that shouldn't get checked in.

Comment: @RubberDuck Yep... That's where I'm at.

Comment: @RubberDuck Just another bit of information, after opening JIT debugger... threw a `StackOverflowException` inside of AvrProjectManagement.dll... There's no excuse for that.

Comment: gitignore.io should do the trick

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek I just updated my answer. Gitignore.io only recently added an ignore file for Atmel Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.atsuo` file is based on the Visual Studio `.suo` [Solution User Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx) file. These files contain user level settings, like open tool windows and set break points, that shouldn't be checked into the repository. Atmel has extended the format and keeps a few other things in there that causes this file to change each time you compile. That's a 2nd very good reason to not check this file in. Leaving it is going to create very noisy commits and made it a pain for anyone you share your code with.

As you noted, Atmel Studio needs this file to function properly, so rather than deleting it, add it to your `.gitignore` file so Git will never track it. (Although, since you've now checked it in, you'll need to remove it from your Git repository and tell git to stop tracking it. `git rm --cached path/to/projectName.atsuo` should do the trick.)

Here's [the .gitignore file I use for my Atmel Studio projects](https://github.com/rubberduck203/XMega-A1-XPlored/blob/master/.gitignore).

```
#Binaries
Debug/
Release/

#User Specific Files
*.atsuo
```

———

A few years on now, I was able to get a `.gitignore` file for Atmel Studio merged into the community supported section of the github/gitignore project.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/community/embedded/AtmelStudio.gitignore

Comment: Gotta love a successfully migrated question! You have a very good understanding of both the Atmel/AVR Studio aspect as well as how to deal with the repositories. While I'm sure this would work I've gone ahead and decided to quit using Atmel's static libraries and just have "links" to all my C/CPP/H files in one single project. This also removes the issue of complete/reference paths when moving the project/solution from one location to the next.

Comment: Happy to help. I'll second the sentiment. It's good to see a successful migration.

Answer (score 2):

The trick with temporary, and output files, in any version control system is to use the "ignore" mechanism.

In the case of git this is done by creating and adding a file in the root of the git directory tree called `.gitignore` which can specify any and all of specific files, directories, wildcards, etc. To see full details type `git help ignore` and do some reading.